# Software compatible with .GHO, or something to convert the image to another format

Tags: linux, disk-image, norton-ghost, bartpe

I've got a .GHO disk image that needs restoring.  Normally we would use BartPE as a Live CD then use Norton Ghost to image the drive.  The machine we are working on doesn't respond to BartPE at all, and so we are looking at using a Linux based Live CD as an option.

Is there a .GHO compatible software that would run on Linux or some method we could use to convert the image to something usable under Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to deal with this is to convert that image to vm image... [Download VMware vCenter Converter](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info/slug/infrastructure_operations_management/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/5_1)

Your other options are [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) (google...) and PartedMagic - http://partedmagic.com/doku.php

Comment: Hiren worked for us. Too bad the machine we're trying to image needs a slightly different image that the earlier models.